# _Complaint vs _Unsubscribe System Data Tables

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, data-views

Wondering if the data from the **_Complaint** system table should match the **_Unsubscribe** data from within the same MID?

I ran a query to pull everyone from the MID that appears in each table and the overlap is 78%.  A high number to be sure, but not enough for me to assume that all those on **_Complaint** should appear on **_Unsubscribe**.

Trying to find all customers who have "opted-out" in one way or another and since a Spam complaint marks an email as "Unsubscribed" I thought there might be something there.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the ISP and SFMC itself. I'll give you an example and steps how to test.

SFMC is broken in the sense that it does not add `Gmail` spam complaints to either `_Unsubscribe` or `_Complaint`.

`Yahoo` and `Outlook` will both get added to the `_Complaint`, `Outlook` however will also trigger a header unsubscribe request with the Spam Complaint, so it will get added to `_Unsubscribe` as well.

Take your top 20 customer email domains and create test accounts; document their interactions and behavior with SFMC.

Step 1) Create 40 test accounts; 20 to test Spam Complaint and 20 to test Header and RMM Unsubscribes.

Step 2) Start with the spam complaints; trigger emails to all 20 accounts and have each report the mail as junk. Do NOT do any other action.

Step 3) Wait 48 hours and then pull the `_Complaint` and `_Unsubscribe` data for both to record the behavior.

Step 4) Now you know which ones go into both. You can also take the remaining 20 test accounts and validate that `_Unsubscribe` is populated as expected or not.

**Conclusion**: A complaint does not always generate an unsubscribe record but it also does not always generate a complaint record either. `Gmail` being a main issue that SFMC doesn't seem to be able to handle. You'll have to test with your top 20 domains.

**Note**: You may have `unsubscribe` in `_Click` as well if you're not using SFMC's subscription center.

Answer (score -1):

Trying to determine this, I caught a lucky point in time where the system was so new that it allowed for a relatively isolated test.

Test 1)  How many Complaints exist?

```
SELECT 
c.SubscriberKey
, c.Domain
, c.OYBAccountID
, c.eventDate AS complaintDate
, c.jobid AS complaintjobid
FROM  _Complaint c

WHERE c.OYBAccountID = xy
```

result: 57 records in my given system

Test 2)

_unsubscribe, LEFT JOIN on _complaint
(=find all unsubs, decorate with the complaint information if available)

```
SELECT 
c.SubscriberKey
, c.Domain
, c.OYBAccountID
, c.eventDate AS complaintDate
, c.jobid AS complaintjobid
, u.jobid AS unsubjobid
, u.eventDate AS unsubDate
FROM _unsubscribe u
LEFT JOIN _Complaint c
on c.SubscriberKey = u.SubscriberKey
WHERE u.OYBAccountID = xy
```

result: 84 records  in my given system, some with complaint fields "null".

So: There are more unsubs than complaints.

Test 3)

_unsubscribe, INNER JOIN on _complaint
(=find all unsubs that also have a complaint record)

```
SELECT 
c.SubscriberKey
, c.Domain
, c.OYBAccountID
, c.eventDate AS complaintDate
, c.jobid AS complaintjobid
, u.jobid AS unsubjobid
, u.eventDate AS unsubDate
FROM _unsubscribe u
INNER JOIN _Complaint c
on c.SubscriberKey = u.SubscriberKey
WHERE c.OYBAccountID = xy
```

result: 57 records in my given system. All complaints are also in _unsubscribe.

In summary this means:

- All complaints are also unsubs
- Not all unsubs are complaints.

In the resulting data for the JOINs, the ComplaintDate always matches the UnsubDate. (I assume there is a different millisecond value, something I've seen elsewhere, there would be no exact match between timestamps in data views). So, a SPAM complaint does create an _unsubscribe record in near-real-time.

An unsubscription of course does not create a complaint record.

Answer (score -2):

_Complaint and _Unsubscribe are technically different data. However from subscriber's behavior perspective, it can case overlap between the two.

So, if I receive an email, I might Mark it as Spam (_Complaint) and later I might also opt out (_Unsubscribe). This is what causes the overlap

If I just mark it as SPAM, it will not create an Unsubscribe record

Marking as Spam doesn't opt out the subscribe in SFMC

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you and that makes sense. 

However, I can confirm that people who appear in the _Complaint table are all marked as unsubscribed and are not mailable.  

That said, I don't think "marking as Spam doesn't opt out the subscribe in SFMC" is accurate. I'm sure it does.

Comment: those on the complaint dataview are no longer 'sendable' and marked as unsub in the UI - this is done to protect SFMC (as well as your own IP and sender rep).  I am not 100% sure on this aspect, but I believe this is then recorded inside of the unsub Dataview.  There may be some sort of delay before it is recorded though.