# Does SFMC automatically unsubscribe complaints?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, data-views, deliverability, inbox

In SFMC, one of the captured data is complaints (in reporting and data view).

1. my understanding is the complaints in SFMC means subscribers who mark the received email in their inbox as spam, is that correct understanding?
2. Does SFMC automatically unsubscribe subscribers who complain?
3. Is it possible to tell which subscribers marked our email as spam? If yes, how/where?

Comment: question 1: what eazyE says; question 2: check this answer:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204337/complaint-vs-unsubscribe-system-data-tables/348468#348468 
for a how-to on determining the overlap. Something about my answer there seems to be not correct, but you can still use those queries ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happens if the ISP participates in a [FBL](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380562&type=1)

> ISP (Internet Service Provider) Feedback Loops (FBLs) are mechanisms that allow ISP users (end subscribers) to click on the “report spam” or “this is spam” button in their email client, which tells their ISP that they find a given email message to be unwanted.

> After an end subscriber clicks on the “report spam” or “this is spam” button in the user interface of a given email client, an “FBL complaint” is sent back to Salesforce Marketing Cloud for processing. Upon receipt of this FBL complaint, the recipient who lodged the complaint will be unsubscribed from mailings from that client. The complaint is logged and the recipient will show up in send stats as a complaint and as an unsubscribe.

You could review the [_complaint](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_complaint.htm&type=5) dataview to see which has been reported